# How can i keep tcp source port for http 307 redirect?

Tags: http, tcp, port

The dafault behavour for 307 redirect is that every new POST http 1.1 request is using different tcp sourcer port. I need a way to change that in order to use the same tcp source port again after 307 code response.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you use a different identifier than the TCP source port? You can never guarantee the source port, as that is decided by the client's OS.

Comment: Exactly, but the provider service is using TCP source port as identifier.. So the question is - is there any chances to keep one source tcp port for full http session with redirects inside?